# logging into youtube from android

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to log into you tube using the following code

```
mService = new YouTubeService("Nothing", developer_key);

//Authentication
try
{
   mService.setUserCredentials(mUsername, mPassword);
}
catch (AuthenticationException e)
{
   Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

but I am getting:
    `ConnectYouTube: com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI`

This code seems pretty basic to me and I can't figure out what mistake am I making here.

Comment: did you check internet permission in Android Manifest File..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have to following permissions:

- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
- android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
- android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS